# How do I read/write to this storage media?

Tags: usb, operating-systems, media

I am using a card reader to connect the USB storage media, and I am sure that it works and has data on it. The media came with a retro-gaming device, it has old MAME games, etc. on it.

But Mac tells me it's unable to process it and prompts for eject or Initialize (which scared me so I did not try, thinking it could format it or something.)

> The disk you attached was not readable by this computer. [ Eject / Ignore / Initialize... ]

By the look of it, I couldn't tell what the format could be. I need some advice on how to proceed.

Any recommendations or ideas are appreciated. e.g. Try VirtualBox and _______ operating system?

[image: Disk Utility Screen Shot]

Comment: Where did you get it from? What do you expect to be on it? 5 partitions in GUID Partition Format suggests some kind of operating system disk.

Comment: The media came with a retro-gaming device, it has old MAME games, etc. on it.

Comment: Then it is most likely some flavour of Linux, probably using ext4. You might be able to use [extFS for Mac by Paragon Software](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/) to read the disk.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try!